# ngx-fullcalendar | how to call events

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am using ngx-fullcalendar and I am having trouble udnerstanding how to call the events.

I simply do this:

```
<ngx-fullcalendar (onDateClick)="dateClick($dateClickInfo)" defaultView="month" [events]="events" [options]="options"></ngx-fullcalendar>
```

where dateClick is:

```
dateClick(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

and the console prints **undefined**

how can i get the event..?

Comment: Please change the `(onDateClick)="dateClick($dateClickInfo)"` to the `(onDateClick)="dateClick($event)"` if `onDateClick` is the output event and you want to get the output event data as a function argument you need to use `$event` istead of `$somethingElse`

Comment: Damn you are right, my ming got really blured... maybe I should just take a break xD. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you too. Glad to help you!